# Can someone get into the UK from Canada if marriage visa was rejected

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, visa-free-entry, canadian-citizens, weddings

My fiancé is Canadian and we applied for a marriage visa to the UK, planning to have the legal wedding in the UK and a celebration in Canada. (We plan to permanently live in Canada and I have the relevant visa for that.) When applying for the marriage visa (lasts 6 months and can only be obtained if we don’t plan to stay in the UK) my fiancé didn’t submit enough information and his application was rejected. He’s flying to England on May 7th and flights are all booked. We will now no longer be able to get officially married in England so will just have a party here as everything is already paid for and then officially get married in August when I move to Canada. We both have a flight to Canada July 14th and have a holiday booked July 1st; we’re going to Malta. My fiancé will just come to the UK without a visa as he will now be just visiting and Canadians don’t need visas in the UK if they’re staying 3 months or less.

I am scared he’ll not get through the border. Will they know about the rejected marriage visa? Will it affect his admission as a visitor?

Comment: You may get better answers if you upload a copy of the refusal notice with personal information blanked out. Is your marriage in Canada in August confirmed, so that he could have proof of that plan if asked? He should also have with him proof of his ties to Canada (job, savings, property etc) along with his travel bookings.

Answer (score 2):

If he has a regular return ticket, it should not be a problem to show he will return to Canada.

Just never lie to immigration officer about the purpose of the trip (unofficial ceremony is enough).

Also having a plan of holidays and of future marriage will help, and possibly also your status on immigrating in Canada could help.

Not having ideas is bad (it could seem he lie).